# UITextView & UITextField not responsive after [self presentViewController: animated: completion:]

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6

I am facing a problem using UITextView & UITextField in Xcode 6.

Say I am having view A (Main View)
After pressing a button, another view B is presented by the following method:

```
B * bView = [[B alloc] initWithNibName:@"B" bundle:nil];
[bView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[self presentViewController:bView animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

In view B, a certain Button is pressed and another view C is presented using the same method:

```
C * cView = [[C alloc] initWithNibName:@"C" bundle:nil];
[cView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[self presentViewController: cView animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

View C has two UITextView. Upon user interaction, the method:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

is called but then nothing happens, the app freezes and everything stops + keyboard is never shown..

**BTW: In simulator, if I am using the the hardware keyboard, everything is working fine. On the device, if i am connecting a bluetooth keyboard, also everything is working fine. Otherwise when I am using iOS keyboard problem occurs..**

**Also, on Xcode 5 everything is working extremely well**

This is the function it is stuck in

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
0x194e6ce74:  movn   x16, #30
0x194e6ce78:  svc    #128
0x194e6ce7c:  ret    -----------> Thread 1 : Signal SIGSTOP
```

Waiting for your responses.

Thanks,
Ahmed

Comment: If you press the pause button (next to the breakpoint toggle button at the bottom) what comes up? It should break in the assembly code and you can read the name of the function its being stuck at. It should give you some clues.

Comment: Are you testing in simulator?

Comment: @ MadhuP: I am testing in both simulator and device, both same behavior (It is not a problem of connecting hardware keyboard)

Comment: @MikeM: can you please send me a screen shot of what you mean because I can't find my way through..

Comment: I posted it in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue.. It seems that in Xcode 6 and iOS 8 it is not possible anymore to set the superviewbounds in viewWillLayoutSubviews method after calling presentViewController.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 550);
}
```

So By removing the

```
self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 550);
```

from the above function, it worked.

Just add

```
VC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(700, 550);
```

in the parent view controller before calling

```
[self presentViewController:VC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

to give the view the correct frame.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Finally! Thank you, this solves the problem on iOS 8 but on iOS 7 you must change superview's bounds or your view size could be wrong. iOS version conditional is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Press pause and see where the run loop is stuck by reading the name of the function it is at:

[image: Pressing Pause]